# How to check if a Scanner is a specific String + any positive integer [Java]

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I need to check if a Scanner is holding this: "add (any integer here)"
Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BottleGame {
    void startGame() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the bottle game! Please type \"help\" to learn about the game.");
        System.out.println("If you already know how the game works, feel free to start!");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        commands(scanner);
    }
    void commands(Scanner myScanner) {
        boolean again = false;
        do {
            String response = myScanner.next();
            if (response.equals("help")) {
                System.out.println("+------------------------+");
                System.out.println("help - brings up this menu");
                System.out.println("add X - makes X bottles");
                System.out.println("remove X - deletes X bottles");
                System.out.println("flip - flips a bottle");
                System.out.println("+------------------------+");
                again = true;
            }
            //Need to check if response equals "add" + any integer here
        }
        while(again == true);
    }
}
```

I commented the spot where I need this, please look for it in the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use regex. Side note, please replace `while(again == true)` with `while(again)`

Comment: Hi, I'm new to java, so I'm not sure how to use regex. What regex would be right for the example?

Comment: `add\\d+` will find `add421` or any other number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for this, something like `"add\\s+\\d+"` which will match the word add followed by one or more white space and then one or more digits with [`String.matches(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)

```
} else if (response.matches("add\\s+\\d+")) {
    System.out.println("Add");
}
```

to then parse that value out, you could group the digits and invoke [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and then use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) like

```
} else if (response.matches("add\\s+\\d+")) {
    int v = Integer.parseInt(response.replaceAll("add\\s+(\\d+)", "$1"));
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How could I save the numbers (d+) into an int variable?

Comment: Hi, this code right here isn't working:  
        if (response.equals("add\\s+\\d+")) {
                String newResponse = response.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
                System.out.println(newResponse);
            } (Sorry about bad formatting) Any ideas why this doesn't work? Nothing prints out.

Comment: @Lyfe **`matches`** not `equals`. And that regex is equivalent to `response.replaceAll("\\D+", "");`

Comment: Hi, what does matches do as opposed to equals?

Comment: @Lyfe [`java.lang.String#matches(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) takes a *regular expression*. `String.equals(Object)` does not (it checks if the two values are **equal** - no regular expression is involved).

Comment: Wow, you're always on this site :P also thanks for clearing it up.